# How to fix "Assert.IsAssignableFrom() Failure: Value is null" in Xunit testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I'm writting some test for a TDD app in Asp. However when I test a Create(Post) controller, the server return me:

```
 Assert.IsAssignableFrom() Failure: Value is null.
```

Here's the repository:

```
public class Repository
{
     private IList<Subject> _subjects = new List<Subject>()
     {
        new Subject() { 
            SubjectId = Guid.Parse("1fe63de5-4408-4d7b-a40a-bad231b7bd9f"), 
            Title = "Math", 
            Credits = 8
            },
        
        new Subject() { 
            SubjectId = Guid.Parse("de331c36-6b31-4dd9-b50d-f677e51b987c"), 
            Title = "Chemistry", 
            Credits = 10,
             Teacher = new Teacher(){
                  Dni = 2210890,
                  FirstName = "Albert",
                  SurName = "Einstein",
                  Email = "Albert_Einstein@gmail.com",
                },
              Students = new List<Student>()
             {
                new Student() {
                    FirstName = "Cristiano",
                    SurName = "Ronaldo",
                    Email = "CristianoRonaldo12@gmail.com",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                },  

                new Student()
                {
                    FirstName = "Leonel",
                    SurName = "Messi",
                    Email = "LeonelMessi12@gmail.com",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                }               
             }
            }
     };
```

And here's the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controler]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class SubjectController : ControllerBase
{
    private Repository _repo;
   
    public SubjectController(Repository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IActionResult CreateSubject(Subject subject)
    {
        if(subject == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subject Object sent is null");
        }

        _repo.Create(subject);
       
       return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the xUnit test code:

```
public class UnitTest2
{
    private SubjectController _context;
    private Repository _repo;  
    public UnitTest2()
    { 
        _repo = new Repository();
        _context = new SubjectController(_repo);
    }
    [Fact]     
    public void CreateSubjectTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var subject = new Subject()
        {
            SubjectId = Guid.Parse("761c6dc1-4b02-4db5-bf91-5452efb44c1a"),
            Title = "History", 
            Credits = 10,
        };

        //Act
        var result = _context.CreateSubject(subject) as ObjectResult;       
        
        //Assert
        Error Message: Assert.IsAssignableFrom() Failure: Value is null
        Expected: typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult)
        Actual:   null
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result);
        Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, result!.StatusCode);
    } 

};
```

I must mention that I'm not using Moq library nor Memory database, just simple Lists. I'm not sure if this detail may help.

Anyway, I'd be really grateful if anybody could bring me some help because I'm new on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your soft casting your `result` into an `ObjectResult`. `as` casting attempts to cast and if it fails returns the default of the casted type (which is null in this case).

Since you're attempting to assert that your `result` is a `CreatedAtRouteResult`, there is not real need to pre-cast it into something. Your test will then fail in a more meaningful way for you.

Comment: More like `as` always return `null` on failure, since you can only use it for reference types and nullable value types.